# What is the fastest way to split a number into parts?

Tags: number-representation

I have very large numbers (million digits).

number = A*10^partlen + B

As of now, I split the numbers by this way:

```
 TotalLen = IntegerLength[a]; 
 partlen = IntegerPart[TotalLen/2];
 Print[First[Timing[A = IntegerPart[number/(10^partlen )]]]];
 Print[First[Timing[B = Mod[number, 10^partlen ]]]]
```

And the timings for a 6 million digits number are:

```
4.703

0.36
```

Converting the number to strings and rebuilding the parts is even slower than this.

Is there any faster way?

Comment: You're aware of `Mod[]`'s partner `Quotient[]`, aren't you? For that matter, have you seen `QuotientRemainder[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Per J.M. suggestion, I've got a ten fold increase in speed:

```
TotalLen = IntegerLength[a]; 

RightLen = Quotient[TotalLen, 2]; 

Print[First[Timing[{A, B} = QuotientRemainder[a, (10^RightLen)]]]];
```

Timing:

```
0.344
```

Although the time decreased but it is yet so large just for pre-processing.

Comment: You didn't totally take my suggestion. Try `RightLen = Quotient[TotalLen, 2];` Also, *Mathematica* is perfectly capable of parallel assignment: `{A, B} = QuotientRemainder[number, 10^RightLen]`.

Comment: `Quotient[]` and `QuotientRemainder[]` are two different functions, see...

Comment: Oh sorry, I mistyped it